# Creating thread for background task servlet

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets

**The scenario of my problem is:**
In my servlet I get a large amount of data from somewhere (not relevant). I have to iterate over all this data and put it in an array, convert it to a JSON object and send it to the client side for viewing. If I do this in a single response it takes a very long time to display the results. Hence, I need to do multithreading.

The created thread needs to keep on adding data to the list while the main thread whenever it gets a request (requests for data keep on coming periodically) sends the present available list.

For instance on first request the response sent is : 1 2 3
Second request : 4 5 6 and so on.

**Now I come to actual problem :** I don't know how to do multithreading in a servlet. I have looked through numerous resources and examples but it only has confused me further. Some examples have created threads right in doGet which I think is very wrong, some have created them in the init() method but I dont know how can I pass parameters and get results from the thread if it is declared in the init method (It cannot be a global variable). Then there are examples of servletContextListener but I havent found anything useful or that makes sense.

Can anyone please guide to me a reliable source or just give me some sort of pseudo code to get a solution to my problem. It would be extremely helpful if the answers are in context with the aforementioned scenario.

Thanks

Comment: Please explain more, once a request is made to your servlet you should go for requesting data(from servlet to external data)? or servlet should do some background about getting data and make it ready for clients?

Comment: For the sake of simplicity the data is already present. Now the background thread needs to start putting that data in a list (It can start doing that so before a request comes). When a request comes, doGet simply responds with the current state of list. All the while the background thread keeps on adding data to the list. Another request comes and the new list is sent and so on.

Comment: If it helps the data was retrieved from a previous request. I am storing that data in servlet context. Now that data is being changed to a list by the thread I want to create

Answer (score 0):

> The created thread needs to keep on adding data to the list while the
>   main thread whenever it gets a request (requests for data keep on
>   coming periodically) sends the present available list.

If I got you correct, you like to get some data as background service and make them ready for clients once they request them(sounds like harvesting data).

Well, creating thread in web-apps, or generally stuffs come with managed environment is different, creating a thread implicitly would cause of memory leak.

One good solution would having a `ThreadPool`(either by container context/ndi or create it manually).
AND it MUST be created in a manageable manner, where you would control it by environment related events.

`ContextListener` is your friend, having a context listener class, like this.

```
public class dear_daemon implements ServletContextListener,Runnable{
ExecutorService the_pool;
Thread the_evil;
/*following get invoked once the context is called*/
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce){
/*initialize the thread-pool, and run evil thread*/}
/*following get invoked once the context is destroying*/
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce){eviling=false;
/*stop evil(this) thread(first), then destroy thread pool*/
}
volatile boolean eviling=true;
public void run(){
 while(eviling){
  /*run Runnable instance which do data fetching using thread-pool*/
 }
}
}
```

And register the listener in `web.xml`

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>dudes.dear_daemon</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Having a class(runnable) which do the data fetching, and invoke it by evil thread, each instance using one thread.

The `ContextLisstener` helps you correctly shutdown and manage init and hult events by container, using the same thing with servlet init is possible, but make sure you do the same thing about hulting with destroy method of servlet.

If you like to do thread-thing about it, make sure you are doing things thread-safe since you have one thing to store data(a list).

If any synchronization is needed(for example ordering the fetched data), make sure you are doing it right, or you will face with deadlocks, or low-performance code.

If any(probably) IO action is needed for getting data, note java IO is blocking, so set appreciated read and connection timeouts, or switch to NIO if you can handle complex NIO stuffs.

If applying these changes make the environment complex, and you like to do alternative solutions, you may simply extract the data fetching from web-profile and run it as a external daemon-service or applciation, where the applciation will pass the fetched data to the server context using calling one of your CGI/Servlet.

Comment: I am sorry I still have confusion. From what I know a servletcontextlistener is for executing code before the web application starts. How can I pass it the table of data in doGet()? From what I can understand this requires the data to be stored somewhere beforehand. ( I think you misunderstood the existence of the said data ... The data is received via ajax request after the web application starts. After this data has been received I want the whole multithreading and data to list conversion to occur)

Comment: @FurqanTariq Each request comes with a(may new) thread for the servlet, so if you get 100 async ajax calls, you will get 100 async servlet call, which each one will be run(invoked) by a thread. Unless you set the(default) multi-thread of context to single.